# Is it possible to add 2 rows of header to a Microstrategy Dossier?

Tags: header, microstrategy, dossier

in Microstrategy Dossier,  is it possible to create 2 rows of header, such that the first row is the grouping information and spans to number of columns to identify as a group? for example : group "Inbound costs" should span to "Dep1 | Dep2 | Dep3" and "Outbound costs should span to " Transportation | Energy | Warehouse " ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit different if you are grouping attributes or metrics, but I think it should work either way.

**If grouping attributes**, that is pretty straightforward. Put the attribute in the columns, then right-click and select "Create Groups...". From there, put the elements into one group that is labeled "Inbound Costs" and make another that is labeled "Outbound Costs". Once you have the group made, then just drag in the original attribute under it. Might need to play with formatting to make sure that the repetitive cells are merged and centered, but that would group the attributes across the columns.

**If grouping metrics**, it is a bit more involved. First, do "Change Visualization" on your grid and set it to "Compound Grid". This will allow you set the different sets of columns that behave differently.

Then, put the "Inbound Costs" into one column set and the "Outbound Costs" into another column set. This groups them, but doesn't label them quite yet.

To label them, right-click on any attribute in the dataset panel and select "Create attribute...". Name the attribute whatever you'd like and have the definition be `"Inbound Costs"` and set the data type to "String". Drag this new attribute above the metrics in the first column group (making sure it is still in the group). Repeat the same for "Outbound Costs" and then work on formatting to merge the repetitive labels and center.

Here is a quick screenshot of how I was able to make it look using some fake data, if that is what you were indeed trying to do.

[image]